# Vim: reverse visual mode perspective

Tags: vim

Let's say you're using vim to select in visual mode. You hit <kbd>v</kbd>, then start moving to the right with <kbd>l</kbd>. Then, let's say you wish to extend your selection to the left, without changing the point at the right. That is, you're satisfied with `'>` but want to change `'<`.

How do you swap so that it is as if you started at `'>` and are selecting to the left, changing `'<`?

I have a vague recollection that I've seen this before, but it's hard to google for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Oops, amazing how posting to stackoverflow can make reading the (F) manual that much easier...

```
3. Changing the Visual area             *visual-change*

                            *v_o*
o           Go to Other end of highlighted text: The current
            cursor position becomes the start of the highlighted
            text and the cursor is moved to the other end of the
            highlighted text.  The highlighted area remains the
            same.
```

Comment: Don't forget capital `O` in blockwise (rectangular) selection, that does not go diagonal: `:help v_O`.

Answer (score 5):

`o`

From the documentation:

```
o           Go to Other end of highlighted text: The current
            cursor position becomes the start of the highlighted
            text and the cursor is moved to the other end of the
            highlighted text.  The highlighted area remains the
            same.
```